# Software PWM without clobbering the CPU?

Tags: c, embedded, pthreads, gpio

This is an academic question (I'm not necessarily planning on doing it) but I am curious about how it would work. I'm thinking of a userland software (rather than hardware) solution.

I want to produce PWM signals (let's say for a small number of digital GPIO pins, but more than 1). I would probably write a program which created a Pthread, and then infinitely looped over the duty cycle with appropriate `sleep()`s etc in that thread to get the proportions right.

Would this not clobber the CPU horribly? I imagine the frequency would be somewhere around the 100 Hz mark. I've not done anything like this before but I can imagine that the constant looping, context switches etc wouldn't be great for multitasking or CPU usage.

Any advice about CPU in this case use and multitasking? FWIW I'm thinking of a single-core processor. I have a feeling answers could range from *'that will make your system unusable'* to *'the numbers involved are orders of magnitude smaller than will make an impact to a modern processor'*!

Assume C because it seems most appropriate.

EDIT: Assume Linux or some other general purpose POSIX operating system on a machine with access to hardware GPIO pins.

EDIT: I had assumed it would be obvious how I would implement PWM with sleep. For the avoidance of doubt, something like this:

```
while (TRUE)
{
    // Set all channels high
    for (int c = 0; x < NUM_CHANNELS)
    {
        set_gpio_pin(c, 1);
    }

    // Loop over units within duty cycle
    for (int x = 0; x < DUTY_CYCLE_UNITS; x++)
    {   
        // Set channels low when their number is up
        for (int c = 0; x < NUM_CHANNELS)
        {
            if (x > CHANNELS[c])
            {
                set_gpio_pin(c, 0);
            }
        }

        sleep(DUTY_CYCLE_UNIT);
    }
}
```

Comment: duty cycle represents the ratio between the time the pin is high and the period of your signal and is given in percentage. 100 Hz is signal frequency and has a period of 10ms.

Comment: You need to specify the characteristics of your PWM, particularly with respect to the accuracy and stability of the output signal.  can you put up with any jitter on the PWM signal in either duty cycle or base frequency?  Software PWM will have a lot of timing jitter.

Comment: Just for hobby purposes, driving a lighting dimmer for example. Accuracy isn't that important. I suppose jitter is expected. As I said, an academic question, not something I'm necessarily going to build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a driver if you can.  If your embedded device has a PWM controller, then fine, else dedicate a hardware timer to generating the PWM intervals and driving the GPIO pins.

If you have to do this at user level, raising a process/thread to a high priority and using sleep() calls is sure to generate a lot of jitter and a poor pulse-width range.

Comment: Most of these modern controllers seem to have several hardware timers, though they don't all have high interrupt priorities.  Not sure about linux, but on other embedded kernels, I would hack the OS timer setup to reduce the OS timer interval to, say, 100us, and bodge the interrupt to run the PWM and also call the OS scheduler entry every 10/100 interrupts.

Comment: Doing it from an efficiently written interrupt function will hardly be noticable in CPU time. Battery life is a different story (i.e. waking up from sleep mode 100x/sec costs a lot of energy). Be sure to read the datasheets on timer functionality, as these tend to be more versatile than many people are aware of!

Comment: @Adriaan - if you are referring to capture/match, be careful... I have had persistent problems with such functionality on <lawyers>'a particular range of controllers'</lawyers>.

Comment: @Martin - that's indeed the most common one. I found also the HET in TI TMS series very useful. Agreed, seldomly used functionality is more likely to contain errors; check errata next to datasheet

Answer (score 2):

You do not very clearly state the ultimate purpose of this, but since you have tagged this embedded and pthreads I will assume you have a dedicated chip with a linux variant running.

In this case, I would suggest the best way to create PWM output is through your main program loop, since I assume the PWM is part of a greater control application. Most simple embedded applications (no UI) can run in a single thread with periodic updates of the GPIOs in your main thread.

For example:

```
InitIOs();

while(1)
{
   // Do stuff
   UpdatePWM();
}
```

That being said, check your chip specification, in most embedded devices there are dedicated PWM output pins (that can also act as GPIOs) and those can be configured simply in hardware by setting a duty cycle and updating that duty cycle as required. In this case, the hardware will do the work for you.

If you can clarify your situation a bit I can likely give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: But `// Do stuff` has no defined duration. I can't see how you could produce a reliable duty cycle this way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do not assume I have access to dedicated PWM pins (hence me having to write the PWM driver code myself).

Comment: Joe, you are correct that "Do stuff" can take an arbitrary amount of time and that depends on how complex "Do stuff" is. Generally speaking, modern chips will be much faster than your duty cycle given that most duty cycle will be in the KHz range, whereas your chip likely runs at several MHz. That being said, if you are concerned about your duty cycle (duty cycles need not be perfect given they roughly simulate analogue signals) you can setup a hardware timer interrupt that will call "UpdatePWM()" every time it hits a pre-determined Tick count. This requires tying up a timer.

Comment: Just as an extra note, keep in mind that keeping your main "update" loop light is important. Again for purely embedded systems with a single process, you can break huge tasks into many "loops" by only partially completing them each cycle. This allows for fast updates of priority tasks (like PWM) while allowing larger computations.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a timer, you can set that up to kick an interrupt each time a new PWM edge is required.  With some clever coding, you can queue these up so the interrupt handler knows which of many PWM channels and whether a high or low going edge is required, and then schedule itself for the next required edge.

If you have enough of these timers, then its even easier as you can allocate one per PWM channel.

On an embedded controller with a low-latency interrupt response, this can produce surprisingly good results.

Answer (score 1):

A better way is probably to use some kind interrupt-driven approach. I suppose it depends on your system, but IIRC Arduino uses interrupts for PWM.

Comment: `sleep()` involves the task scheduler, which already uses the system timer's interrupt for preemption or for waking up from idle.

Comment: @Joe: It depends exactly on how you implement it, but there seems to be some support for user-space interrupts in linux (mainly used for user-space drivers, but it is probably possible to use it for other things).

Comment: @pmjordan Are you saying that sleep would therefore be suitable?

Answer (score 1):

100Hz seems about doable from user space. Typical OS task scheduler timeslices are around 10ms, too, so your CPU will already be multitasking at about that interval. You'll probably want to use a high process priority (low niceness) to ensure the sleeps won't overrun (much), and keep track of actual wall time and potentially adjust your sleep values down based on that feedback to avoid drift. You'll also need to make sure the timer the kernel uses for this on your hardware has a high enough resolution!

If you're very low on RAM and swapping heavily, you could run into problems with your program being paged out to disk. Also, if the kernel is doing other CPU-intensive stuff, this would also introduce unacceptable delays. (other, lower priority user space tasks should be ok) If keeping the frequency constant is critical, you're better off solving this in the kernel (or even running a realtime kernel).

Comment: 100Hz PWM frequency means that you need to shift the edges about at some large multiple of that (256x to get even an 8-bit-equivalent PWM).  You can't do that off a 10ms scheduler tick - for 8-bit-equivalent the edge resolution needs to be ~40us!

Answer (score 1):

I fail to understand why you would want to do PWM in software with all of the inherent timing jitter that interrupt servicing and software interactions will introduce (e.g. the PWM interrupt hits when interrupts are disabled, the processor is servicing a long uninterruptible instruction, or another service routine is active).  Most modern microcontrollers (ARM-7, ARM Cortex-M, AVR32, MSP, ...) have timers that can either be configured to produce or are dedicated as PWM generators.  These will produce multiple rock steady PWM signals that, once set up, require zero processor input to keep running.  These PWM outputs can be configured so that two signals do not overlap or have simultaneous edges, as required by the application.

If you are relying on the OS sleep function to set the time between the PWM edges then this will run slow.  The sleep function will set the minimum time between task activations and the time between these will be delayed by the task switches, the presence of a higher priority thread or other kernel function running.

Comment: Like I said, it was an academic exercise about doing PWM on general purpose hardware, not actually trying to get something specific done. I seem to have got my answer, which is "it'll work badly but you should be using specialist hardware".

Answer (score 1):

Using a thread and sleeping on an OS that is not an RTOS is not going to produce very accurate or consistent results.

A better method is to use a timer interrupt and toggle the GPIO in the ISR.  Unlike using a hardware PWM output on a hardware timer, this approach allows you to use a single timer for multiple signals and for other purposes.  You will still probably see more jitter that a hardware PWM and the practical frequency range and pulse resolution will be much lower that is achievable in hardware, but at least the jitter will be in the order of microseconds rather than milliseconds.